# SELECT from a table where a a column contains only elements from another column

Tags: mysql, database, select, optimization, database-design

In a definitely wrong code, I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE
table2.items CONTAINS ONLY ELEMENTS FROM table1.item
```

This is a little confusing, but I'l try to explain:

I have one table (table1) which has a column with one element in each row (let's call them A, B, C, D)

```
id - [item]

1 - ["A"]
2 - ["B"]
3 - ["C"]
4 - ["D"]
```

Then I have another table (table2) which its columns contains strings like:

```
TABLE2
row# - [items]

row1 - ["A, B"]
row2 - ["A, B, C"]
row3 - ["A, B, C, E"]
```

What I want is select only the rows from table2 that contains only elements present in table1, so row1 and row2, in this example.

Is it possible to do that without changing the tables' structure? Otherwise, which changes do I need to make?

---------[edit]-------------

So I changed my structure, to be able to use the IN operator and it worked (almost) fine!
A new problem has arrived though.
Since my table2 strings had different lengths, my new table2 has some empty cells.

---[update]---

So if I'm trying to check if

```
|item1|item2|item3|item4| row |
|  A  |  B  |  C  |     |  2  |
```

row2 is in table1.item (same as above), one of the conditions I ask for is

```
WHERE NULL IN table1.item
```

and it isn't! What I need is to only check if the item is in the other table when the item isn't NULL. I'l try playing with that

Comment: So what's the new table2 structure?  For this minimal example, I suppose you'd only need a unique identifier (ID), a non-unique value (A, or B, or C, etc), and a group_id to associate the related ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it is possible.  One easy way is with a subquery.  That would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE some_value IN (SELECT some_value from table2);
```

This will return everything from table1 where some_value exists in table2's column `some_value`

If your table2 were something like this:

```
|ID | Value | Group_id|
| 1 |   A   |   1     |
| 2 |   B   |   1     |
| 3 |   C   |   1     |
| 4 |   A   |   2     |
| 5 |   B   |   2     |
```

This would represent 'A, B, C' all in group 1, and 'A, B' in group 2.  Now, you would very easily be able to retrieve all values associated with any group, in distinct rows.  As far as I can tell from your initial question, this table shouldn't have any NULL values in it (as you mentioned in your update)

Now, to determine all groups which have ONLY elements that exist in table1, you might:

```
SELECT group_id FROM table2 WHERE group_id NOT IN (SELECT group_id FROM table2 WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT value from table1));
```

This generates a set of results containing all values in table1, then returns all group_ids with values outside of that set, then negates that.  Kinda complicated, and there are probably better ways to do it...

Comment: Wouldn't that need my table2 to have separated columns for each "item", instead of just a string with all items?

Comment: It would, yes.  What you need to research is called normalization.  We want to have only single values in any given 'cell'.  So for your example you might want to have a third table which would hold each value.  For example:  Instead of having Table2.Row1 hold both 'A' and 'B' , you might assign that row a Group_ID, create a third table called Groups, insert two lines into Group_IDs (one row for each value), and give these lines the same Group_ID that Table2.Row1 will now have in place of values.  This is a common way to associate numerous values with one 'parent' record

Comment: After some work, it is almost working. Mind taking a look at the edited part of the OP?

Comment: I have done some not-so-pretty work arounds with IFNULL(). Seems like it works as intended now! Thanks for your help, time and patience :D

Answer (score 2):

You have a very poor data layout.  In SQL, it is a bad idea to store lists of things in rows.  Here are some reasons:

- In relational data models, each column should store one "thing".
- Relational databases have a great way of storing lists.  It is called a table.
- The database cannot enforce foreign key relationships.

Sometimes, you are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  MySQL has some functionality that can help.  For instance, if the "list" were just comma separated strings:

```
SELECT t2.items
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON find_in_set(t1.item, t2.items) > 0
GROUP BY t2.items  -- or this should really be an id column if available
HAVING COUNT(*) = LENGTH(t2.items) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t2.ITEMS, ',', ''));
```

Your list format has spaces, so you need to remove them:

```
SELECT t2.items
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON find_in_set(t1.item, replace(t2.items, ' ', '')) > 0
GROUP BY t2.items  -- or this should really be an id column if available
HAVING COUNT(*) = LENGTH(t2.items) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t2.ITEMS, ',', ''));
```